# Tangent space to World Space (TBN Matrix)

Tags: c++, matrix, graphics, depth-buffer

I'm building a renderer using rasterization and depth-buffering in the CPU and now I've included normals maps. Everything works like you can see in the next image:

[image]

The issue is that, even that it works, I don't understand WHY! The implementation is against what I think. This is the code to get the normal at each fragment:

```
const Vector3D TexturedMaterial::getNormal(const Triangle3D& triangle_world, const Vector2D& text_coords) const { 
   Vector3D tangent, bitangent;
   calculateTangentSpace(tangent, bitangent, triangle_world);
   // Gets the normal from a RGB Texture [0,1] and maps it to [-1, 1]
   const Vector3D normal_tangent = (Vector3D) getTextureColor(m_texture_normal, m_texture_normal_width, m_texture_normal_height, text_coords);
   const Vector3D normal_world = TangentToWorld(normal_tangent, tangent, bitangent, normal_tangent);

   return normal_world;
}


void TexturedMaterial::calculateTangentSpace(Vector3D& tangent, Vector3D& bitangent, const Triangle3D& triangle_world) const {
  const Vector3D q1 = triangle_world.v2.position - triangle_world.v1.position;
  const Vector3D q2 = triangle_world.v3.position - triangle_world.v2.position;

  const double s1 = triangle_world.v2.texture_coords.x - triangle_world.v1.texture_coords.x;
  const double s2 = triangle_world.v3.texture_coords.x - triangle_world.v2.texture_coords.x;

  const double t1 = triangle_world.v2.texture_coords.y - triangle_world.v1.texture_coords.y;
  const double t2 = triangle_world.v3.texture_coords.y - triangle_world.v2.texture_coords.y;


  tangent = t2 * q1 - t1 * q2;
  bitangent = -s2 * q1 + s1 * q2;

  tangent.normalize();
  bitangent.normalize();
}
```

My confusion is here:

```
const Vector3D TexturedMaterial::TangentToWorld(const Vector3D& v, const Vector3D& tangent, const Vector3D& bitangent, const Vector3D& normal) const {
  const int handness = -1; // Left coordinate system
  // Vworld = Vtangent * TBN
  Vector3D v_world = {
    v.x * tangent.x + v.y * bitangent.x + v.z * normal.x,
    v.x * tangent.y + v.y * bitangent.y + v.z * normal.y,
    v.x * tangent.z + v.y * bitangent.z + v.z * normal.z,
  };
  // Vworld = Vtangent * TBN(-1) = V * TBN(T)
  Vector3D v_world2 = {
    v.x * tangent.x   + v.y * tangent.y   + v.z * tangent.z,
    v.x * bitangent.x + v.y * bitangent.y + v.z * bitangent.z,
    v.x * normal.x    + v.y * normal.y    + v.z * normal.z,
  };

  v_world2.normalize();
  // return handness * v_world; --> DOES NOT WORK
  return handness * v_world2; --> WORKS
}
```

Assuming that I'm working with row vectors:

```
V = (Vx, Vy, Vz)

      [Tx Ty Tz]
TBN = [Bx By Bz]
      [Nx Ny Nz]

          [Tx Bx Nx]
TBN(-1) = [Ty By Ny] // Assume basis are orthogonal TBN(-1) = TBN(T)
          [Tz Bz Nz]
```

Then, if T, B and N are the basis vectors of the TBN expressed in the **world** coordinate system the transformations should be:

```
 Vworld = Vtangent * TBN
 Vtangent = Vworld * TBN(-1)
```

But, in my code I am doing exactly the opposite. To transform the normal in tangent space to world space I am multiplying by the inverse of the TBN.

What I am missing or misunderstanding? Is the assumption that T, B and N are expressed in the world coordinate system wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct - the second version is wrong. A more intuitive way to see that is analyzing what happens when the tangent space normal is `(0, 0, 1)`. In this case, you obviously want to use the triangle normal, which is exactly what the first version should do.

However, you are feeding a wrong parameter:

```
const Vector3D normal_world = TangentToWorld(normal_tangent,
                                             tangent, bitangent, normal_tangent);
```

The last parameter needs to be the triangle normal, not the normal you fetch from the texture.

Comment: A tangent space normal of `(0, 0, 1)` would mean that this vector is perpendicular to the surface. Multiplying this by the TBN matrix yields exactly the triangle normal (which is also perpendicular to the surface of the triangle). That makes sense.

Comment: The matrix should be composed with the triangle normal not the tangent normal because the tangent normal is in tangent space, not in world space like the tangent and bitangent. Therefore, the tangent normal could point in a direction that is not perpendicular to the tangent and bitangent. Using the triangle normal we know that it is in world space (like the tangent and bitangent) and that is perpendiular to them (at least in my simple case) and thus they define a valid transformation matrix. I am right? Thank you btw!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly. Were you rephrasing my answer? Have you tried it - did it work?

Comment: I thought about it, I tried it and it worked. I was trying to reason why I should use the triangle normal instead of the tangent normal